# How to check that date is correct when using date_select

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I search a solution for validate user birth date, for example if user try to submit only day and month but he doesn't select year, date will be invalid, but rails don't show any exception or error if year is not set for example but he skip date, and date will not be updated

I found some old answers about the subject, and it seem not to be clear for me. (note i use **date_select** helper in my view)

I did already a search about date validation but I'm looking for an effective solution that is **up to date**

i will be thankful for any suggestion. thank you

Comment: What's wrong with the `date_select` that's built into Rails?

Comment: no problem with date_select !!! why ? my problem is about how to validate date !

Comment: What do you mean by "validate date"? What kind of validation are you trying to do?

Comment: validate date mean that date sent by user is valid, for example if he just choose day and month but not a year from date_select, date will be invalid, also if he choose 31 February it's not a valid date ....

Comment: @FarleyKnight i update my question to be clear :)

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.parse(..) will raise an error if the date is not valid:

```
[1] pry(main)> DateTime.parse("Feb 31, 2013")
ArgumentError: invalid date
from (pry):1:in `parse'
[2] pry(main)> e = begin; DateTime.parse("Feb 31, 2013"); rescue => e; e; end
=> #<ArgumentError: invalid date>
```

So just capture the error to check for a valid date:

```
def valid_date?(string)
  begin
    DateTime.parse(string)
    return true
  rescue => e
    return false
  end
end
```

Comment: this solution is client side :/ imagine that javascript is deactivated, i need server validation with rails

Comment: it seem that rails take car of the case when that is 31 Feb and update this from 31 Feb to 2 March ... still case when user select just day and month (but not year)

Comment: You need to provide a complete set of validations you're looking for.